# Getting last update information / Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When working with a database on `Firebase`, is it possible from within an iOS app to check the date(& time) a document was last updated using some standard API? I mean without implementing my own system to know when it was last time touched.

It would be convenient if there was a field *"lastUpdate"* time-stamp for instance.

Comment: You must use firestore in this case as it provides you cloud function which can be used to trigger an event(in your case storing lastUpdate)

Comment: I am actually using Firestore. When I get a document using this code "for document in querySnapshot!.documents {.....}" How do I know the date-time this document was last updated?

Comment: I don't think there is standard API for that. You need to make sure to add/edit a Timestamp each time the doc is created/updated. I used Cloud Functions to implement it once for all : I wrote a function that is triggered each time a doc is created/updated to a given firestore reference. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events

Comment: You can use Cloud functions on the realtime database and firestore. Regarding the last update time you can actually do this with the server timestamp. This is a javascript example but it will exist in swift as well you set your field to `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` and then in your security rules you set it to `request.resource.data.dateUpdated == request.time` this will set the document field to the last updated

Comment: @Michel: if you're using Firestore, please tag the question with `google-cloud-firestore` instead of `firebase-realtime-database`. Aside from that: neither database has a built-in auto-timestamp for writes. If you want such a field, you will have to add it yourself, either from the client, or from Cloud Functions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Neither the Firebase Realtime Database nor Cloud Firestore automatically adds a timestamp field to the data for writes.

If you want such a field, you will have to add it yourself, either from the client, or from Cloud Functions.

For a simple example of the latter, which tracks when a node in the database was last modified, see [this folder in the `functions-samples` repo](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/Node-8/lastmodified-tracking). The main code:

```
exports.touch = functions.database.ref('/chat/{message}').onWrite(
    (change, context) => admin.database().ref('/lastmodified').set(context.timestamp));
```

Comment: Yes. I finally just added a simple lastTouch integer field which perfectly does the job. When adding a timestamp, using a server based timestamp should be more reliable than a client based one. Because independent of the client and the same time reference for all clients.